# eCharts: Allow user to resize axis

Tags: echarts

Can we give user control to drag and increase height of y-axis in eCharts.

One solution I can think of is make parent div resizable and adjust height of chart accordingly.

But I would like to know if eCharts has any direct option/property/method to do that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in mind? yAxis is not HTML-element, you can't resize it like div. Axis size depends on chart data. You have little control over the scale with attribute `max` and increase y data.

What is the main problem you are trying to solve?